# Dynamic two-dimensional array of pointers to strings in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc

I would like to create a dynamic two-dimensional array of pointers to strings, like in the diagram below:

[image]

The program below is an extracted part of a program, and allocating dynamically stack A seems to work fine, but I'm having trouble creating a dynamic two-dimensional array of pointers to the cells of A.

```
// Global
char **stack_A;  // dynamic array of strings
char ***stack_B; // dynamic array of pointers to strings

int main(){
    stack_A = malloc(sizeof(char *)); 
    stack_B = malloc(sizeof(char **));
    function(); 
    return 0;
}

void function(){
    // example for first entry 

    char *text = "some text";
    stack_A = realloc(stack_A, sizeof(char *)*strlen(text));
    stack_A[0] = strdup(text);
   
    stack_B[0] = realloc(stack_B[0], sizeof(char **));
    stack_B[0][0] = *stack_A[0];
    printf("%s", **stack_B[0][0]); // I want to output "some text"
}
```

**Update:** both the comment and answer was helpful in resolving the issue.

Comment: `stack_A = realloc(A, sizeof(char *)*strlen(text));` --> Here you increase the size of stack_A to the length of the text_string... why is that?

Comment: I might have gotten it wrong, but I just need to increase a cell of stack_A to make some space for "text".

Comment: `stack_B[0][0] = *stack_A[0];` The lvalue is of type `char*` while the rvalue is of type `char`...

Comment: What is `A`? And `stack_B[0] = realloc(stack_B[0], sizeof(char **));` will invoke *undefine d behavior* by using value of buffer allocated via `malloc()` and not initialized, which is indeterminate.

Comment: Thank you @MikeCAT, it's a typo. I've edited the question.

Comment: regarding: `char ***stack_B;` Please read [three star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: `char ***stack_B` is not a 2D array of strings, it is a pointer to a pointer to a string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not copying the pointer to the string, but the first charachter of the string:

`stack_B[0][0] = *stack_A[0];` -> `*stack_A` means the first array in the group of arrays.
it means the same as `stack_A[0]`.

`*stack_A[0]` means the first char in `stack_A[0]`: `'s'`

You need to copy the **pointer**, not the first letter:
`stack_B[0][0] = *stack_A[0]` becomes `stack_B[0][0] = stack_A[0]`.